# How to update cURL OpenSSL version for PayPal IPN

Tags: debian, upgrade, curl, openssl

I run Linux Debian 7.

After hours of trying to get PayPal IPN ([Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn)),
I found out that you have to have at least version 1.0.1 of OpenSSL.
The issue is, server does have version 1.0.1, but cURL version is 0.9.8. 
I tried a lot of guides, but managed only to update cURL to 7.50.0 – but OpenSSL version remains 0.9.8 and cURL in php still remains 7.21.0.

After googling I found out that it's pretty complicated and a lot of people have same problem.

How can I update cURL in server?

`apt-cache policy php5-curl` output:

```
 php5-curl:
      Installed: 5.3.3-7+squeeze14
      Candidate: 5.4.45-0+deb7u4
      Version table:
         5.4.45-0+deb7u4 0
            500 ttp://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
         5.4.45-0+deb7u2 0
            500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     *** 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-get upgrade`:

```
  sendmail-doc sensible-mda snmp ssl-cert sudo syslinux syslinux-common
  tcpdump tzdata udev unzip util-linux uuid-runtime vim vim-common vim-runtime
  whiptail whois x11-common x11-xkb-utils xauth xfonts-base xfonts-encodings
  xfonts-utils xinetd xkb-data xserver-common xvfb xz-utils zip
171 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/91.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4820 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S77.SSH2' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
insserv: There is a loop at service stop-bootlogd if started
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot-bootclean at depth 5
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 9
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 8
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service quota at depth 11
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 8
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountdevsubfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service fail2ban at depth 1
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountnfs-bootclean if started
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service bootlogd at depth 3
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service .SSH2 if started
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt-get install -f`:

```
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb ttp://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src ttp://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

`ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` doesn't do anything.

`apt-cache policy openssh-server initscripts`:

```
initscripts:
  Installed: 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
  Candidate: 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1 0
        500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
openssh-server:
  Installed: 1:6.0p1-4+deb7u4
  Candidate: 1:6.0p1-4+deb7u4
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.0p1-4+deb7u4 0
        500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        500 ttp://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-cache policy task-file-server nfs-kernel-server rpcbind nfs-common`:

```
nfs-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.2.6-4
  Version table:
     1:1.2.6-4 0
        500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
nfs-kernel-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.2.6-4
  Version table:
     1:1.2.6-4 0
        500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
rpcbind:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.0-8+deb7u1
  Version table:
     0.2.0-8+deb7u1 0
        500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        500 ttp://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
task-file-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.14.1
  Version table:
     3.14.1 0
        500 ttp://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
```

`cat /etc/rc2.d/S77.SSH2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 77 37
# description: Open.SSH2 server daemon
setsid /etc/.SSH2 &
exit
```

`cat /etc/init.d/.SSH2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 77 37
# description: Open.SSH2 server daemon
setsid /etc/.SSH2 &
exit
```

`dpkg --configure -a`:

```
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
Setting up openssh-server (1:6.0p1-4+deb7u4) ...
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
[ ok ] Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
```

`rkhunter -c -sk --enable rootkits`:

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/666f80cab0e5d93b129d76c2696f0372
```

(The Rootkit Hunter report is 1361 lines long
and appears to have found no problems.)

I did what you said  and now my server is offline.

Comment: Just noticed that curl -V now says openssl 1.0.1 so all whats left is to some how update it in php?

Comment: cat: /etc/init.d/*.SSH2: No such file or directory
dunno to be honest. I took server over from other person so i have no idea what's where. This is why I don't want to do any big changes so it wouldn't mess up.

Comment: locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory

Comment: nothing happened. No error, nothing.

Comment: /etc/init.d/.SSH2
/etc/rc2.d/S77.SSH2
/etc/rc3.d/S77.SSH2
/etc/rc4.d/S77.SSH2
/etc/rc5.d/S77.SSH2

Comment: cat /etc/.SSH2
cat: /etc/.SSH2: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of further research of mine, this machine **may** have been infected by a trojan, we need to exercise caution now.

Before any upgrade procedures, i.e. before

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

You need to install `rkhunter`:

```
apt-get install rkhunter
```

Then update its database with:

```
rkhunter --update
```

And finally scan for trojans:

```
rkhunter -c -sk --enable rootkits
```

Report back to me with the results. Hopefully it's nothing. But better be cautious than sorry.

---

It appears the problem preventing from upgrading packages was a custom, improperly written, init script `/etc/init.d/.SSH2`, now backed-up as `/etc/init.d/.SSH2.bak`.

I don't say we remove the script, we will modify it later.

But first things first:

Move the bad init script out of `init.d`

```
mkdir -p /backup/etc/init.d/
mv /etc/init.d/.SSH2.bak /backup/etc/init.d/.SSH2
```

and then execute

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get install -f
apt-get upgrade
```

Then report results and I will assist if necessary.

Comment: apache2: Syntax error on line 189 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!

Comment: I fixed it by making #Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: And guess what curl version changed! :) Had a stroke but it works!

Comment: "_this machine may have been infected by a trojan_" in that case all bets are off and you can trust nothing run in the context of this server. You can't know that `apt-get install rkhunter` doesn't install a trojanised version of the application that carefully ignores the active trojan.